# Add a code snippet on the page if a certain page type/url in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wanting to add a no index tag on every page that is a villa landing page, like this:

https://villaagogo.com/villas/florida-villas/orlando-villas/highgate-park/highgate-park-gorgeous-3-bedroom-florida-villa-in-davenport

How can I target this inside my main Layout file to add the code. Every villa landing page begins with: https://villaagogo.com/villas/

All of the other pages, are like this:
https://villaagogo.com/florida-villas/orlando-villas
https://villaagogo.com/florida-villas

etc.

I do not know anything about C#, I am literally Googling around and trying to add it myself whilst the developer is away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code inside  element of your layout:

```
@if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://villaagogo.com/villas/"))
{
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
}
```

This will check current request URL and if it starts with the specific string, it will add the meta tag to the page.

A better way would be to put the URL in app settings in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UrlStartsWithForNoIndexing" value="https://villaagogo.com/villas/" />
</appSettings>
```

then you can use that in your layout:

```
@if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlStartsWithForNoIndexing"]))
{
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
}
```

Comment: The top one worked a treat, for some reason the other one produced an error on the site but this will do whilst I am rebuilding the site. Thanks again

Comment: For the second solution to work, you need to add a using statement at the top of your layout as follows:

    @using System.Configuration